# How Prototype Scope work in Spring Web Application.?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm use prototype scope in spring web application. In my web application multiple users.

```
a) How to work prototype scope in web application for multiple user.
```

and

```
b) How to work session scope in web application for multiple user.
```

i want following,

```
 c) I want each user have separate instances, which spring scope is better to use  for my web application.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)

a) The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made (that is, it is injected into another bean or it is requested via a programmatic getBean() method call on the container)

b) With session scope Spring container will create a brand new instance of bean for the lifetime of a single HTTP Session.

c) That depends, if your bean will have specific configuration which comes from logged user details session, scope will be right choice, if your bean will have constant configuration then you choose singleton scope, prototype scope is usefull for multithreading stuff. So bean scope depends on what it is used for. I think you don't provide enough information to help you which scope you should choose but I hope my tips will help.

Comment: i want every user have its separate instance of configuration bean for multiple service.

Comment: can u explain me difference between prototype vs session scope for multiple users in web application

Comment: When user login into application HttpSession is created and after that also bean with session  scope is created (Spring creates new instance of this bean each time when new user login in your application).

In prototype scope bean is created each time when we request for this beans (independ if user is login in to application or not).

Comment: can prototype scope created separate bean instance for multiple user..

Comment: It will create seperate bean even when user isn't login. I suggest to create new question and describe more detailed your business case and then I will try to help you more.

Answer (score 3):

For choosing the appropriate scope please note the following definitions first:

> **Singleton:** This scope provides bean definition for only a single instance per Spring IoC container.

- usage : Use singleton bean for when you need stateless beans.
- example in real world : connection to a database, A data access object or repository

> **Prototype:** This provides scope for a single bean definition to create a new instance every time is needed without considering
>   session.The container also does not manage the complete lifecyle of
>   the bean. It initiates, configures and assembles a prototype bean and
>   then hands it over to the client.

- **usage:** when the bean carries a state i.e. its stateful. so each user has it's own state.
- **example:** Entities.

> **Request:** This provides scope for a bean definition to an HTTP-request.

- usage: when the information is valid during request.
- example: requested Search data

> **Session:** This provides scope for a bean definition to an HTTP-session.

- usage: when the user information is valid during the whole session.
- example: shopping card data , granted authorization information

> **Global-session:** This provides scope for a bean definition to an Global HTTP-session.

- usage: it is more or less similar to session scope however if you consider this scope in a portal application, the bean could be shared among the whole portlets

Comment: can u suggest me how to use session scope.?